# Angular - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: StoreModule.forRoot() called twice

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

In Angular-13 project, I am implementing @ngrx/store in the CoreModule for Layout Customization.

This is shown in the diagram below:

[image: CoreModule]

Apart from the AppModule, I have these Modules:

- CoreModule
- AdminModule

The Layout is in CoreModule. Then, the @ngrx/store is also implemented in the CoreModule. Also, CoreModule is imported in AdminModule.

**state.ts:**

```
import {UiState} from './ui/state';

export interface AppState {
    auth: any;
    ui: UiState;
}
```

reducer.ts:

```
import {
    NAVBAR_DARK_VARIANTS,
    NAVBAR_LIGHT_VARIANTS,
    SIDEBAR_DARK_SKINS,
    SIDEBAR_LIGHT_SKINS
} from '../../utils/themes';
import * as Actions from './actions';
import {UiAction} from './actions';
import initialState, {UiState} from './state';

export function uiReducer(state: UiState = initialState, action: UiAction) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Actions.TOGGLE_SIDEBAR_MENU:
            return {
                ...state,
                menuSidebarCollapsed: !state.menuSidebarCollapsed
            };
        case Actions.TOGGLE_CONTROL_SIDEBAR:
            return {
                ...state,
                controlSidebarCollapsed: !state.controlSidebarCollapsed
            };
        case Actions.TOGGLE_DARK_MODE:
            let variant: string;
            let skin: string;
            if (state.darkMode) {
                variant = NAVBAR_LIGHT_VARIANTS[0].value;
                skin = SIDEBAR_LIGHT_SKINS[0].value;
            } else {
                variant = NAVBAR_DARK_VARIANTS[0].value;
                skin = SIDEBAR_DARK_SKINS[0].value;
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                navbarVariant: variant,
                sidebarSkin: skin,
                darkMode: !state.darkMode
            };
        case Actions.SET_NAVBAR_VARIANT:
            let navbarVariant: string;
            if (state.darkMode) {
                navbarVariant = action.payload || NAVBAR_DARK_VARIANTS[0].value;
            } else {
                navbarVariant =
                    action.payload || NAVBAR_LIGHT_VARIANTS[0].value;
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                navbarVariant
            };
        case Actions.SET_SIDEBAR_SKIN:
            let sidebarSkin: string;
            if (state.darkMode) {
                sidebarSkin = action.payload || SIDEBAR_DARK_SKINS[0].value;
            } else {
                sidebarSkin = action.payload || SIDEBAR_LIGHT_SKINS[0].value;
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                sidebarSkin
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**core.module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminHeaderComponent } from './components/layouts/admin-header/admin-header.component';
import { AdminSidebarComponent } from './components/layouts/admin-sidebar/admin-sidebar.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/errors/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { authReducer } from './store/auth/reducer';
import { uiReducer } from './store/ui/reducer';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminHeaderComponent,
    AdminSidebarComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ui: uiReducer}),
  ],
  exports: [
    AdminHeaderComponent,
    AdminSidebarComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CoreModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


app-routing.module.ts:

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from 'src/app/core/components/errors/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'admin',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: 'page-not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent, data: {breadcrumb: 'Page Not Found'} },
  {
    path: 'admin',
  loadChildren: () => import('./features/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
  },
  { path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'page-not-found', pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When I serve the Angular Application, I got this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: StoreModule.forRoot() called twice. Feature modules should use StoreModule.forFeature() instead.
> TypeError: StoreModule.forRoot() called twice. Feature modules should use StoreModule.forFeature() instead.
> at Object._provideForRootGuard [as useFactory] (ngrx-store.mjs:1294:1

If I comment out **StoreModule.forRoot({ui: uiReducer})** in CoreModule, the error is no more there.

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Call `forFeature` ?

Comment: @temp_user - When I replaced forRoot with forFeature in CoreModule, I got this error:     Argument of type '{ ui: (state: UiState | undefined, action: UiAction) => UiState; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FeatureSlice<unknown, Action>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ui' does not exist in type 'FeatureSlice<       and  ui: uiReducer   is highlighted

Comment: Use it correctly too ...

Comment: @temp_user - How do you mean?

Comment: @Ayobamilaye would suggest to user angular console or nx console plugin to create the store. This was it will update your required files through schematics